# What is the meaning of the noun "savaging" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a definition for the word "reel" from Oxford Dictionary.

"Reel"
feel shocked, bewildered, or giddy.
"the Prime Minister was reeling from **a savaging** inflicted in the Commons"

What does "**a savaging**" mean here?

Savaging noun (source:thefreedictionary)
5. an uncivilized human being.
6. a fierce, brutal, or cruel person.
7. a rude, boorish person.

The definitions above describe people but this is definitely an action as the verb "inflicted" follows.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "savaging" does not appear to be in TFD, instead you are redirected to "savage", and you are reading the definitions of the noun "savage".

"Savaging" is closely derived from the present participle/gerund of the verb, and refers to "an act of being *fierce or ferocious; wild; untamed.*"

Using the verb meaning, one may be literally savaged by a wild beast such as a lion or tiger, or figuratively, severely wounded by criticism. As this "savaging" was inflicted in the commons, we can assume that it means that the Prime Minister was verbally attacked in a fierce manner by other MPs. That is, his policy was strongly attacked and he was unable to defend it.

Comment: Using the verb meaning, one may be literally savaged by a wild beast such as a lion or tiger, or figuratively, severely wounded by criticism.

Comment: Yes, I'll use that, thank you.

Comment: Actually, I think I should be more precise. If you are savaged by e.g. a lion, you are definitely injured, but a careful writer might think that a politician 'savaged' by one or more critics is not necessarily injured, either in the feelings or reputation. The verb usually seems to mean 'strongly criticise'. Also I would note that the usage is mainly found in tabloid newspapers, and is a cliché often found in lazy writing.